# Text stuck one to another and cant get spacing

Tags: html, css

I can't get my spacing between:  element and - Fleming used the name penicillin for the antibiotic. or any other.
Also the same  text is stuck to the div title, and the text isnt aligned to right for some reason i dont know how to fix that.
UPDATE PICTURE: [UPDATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCIIS.png)
UPDATE 2: So i cant seem to center this text no matter what (dont want to use padding/margin) here is the picture, the picture and the code:
[UPDATE2PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DubTr.png)

````
```<section  class="projects">
             <h3>My Projects</h3>
            
             <div id="projects">
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Tribute%20Project/TributeProject.html" target="_blank">
          <img class="project-image"src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AIL4fc-P1dxeGJ0x4lnCNPzlLTbC_BP83S52oi2yMO1IWGRGDTx_O9_HBs26kpAgxLuaAdQTTwiKkF-43w4epoR4F7HIPYMvi185i7yG8IE9UWCemC_Fxa7NShRPxR3TjX1aAyLc8NBSq_rub1lIBircelKZ6d_uZ24C0T2QTD9z52T85UdvnUGlS9y2rC4ND-zAu7nogoBNMDILoo7gv0HPjnyKHDUe_KTwBayCCSf9la_s6OFYhm1Fpui69Hshe1ir3p9bEyY5S6sc23ee8lkPKl9fvl55d9cM4kY8rJHO3xmGRwgGb52-HCqXiTNPWLWcnmQSkmIeGoEvuYoHf6EzLxgd63DJGoxgg3iUXujJwydwJ9vfwJBlLXY3swaKIqpzyLd0g8L9yNejnDl2uW7Xqpnh53IKF_ZPwJVj9P6ubzSc8Pwi8lye4P0xDpAPva2k-2G-TzL4JML9v0NILIfcOD9mgIg-hJP5UcsABeS52y4v_F63zBxLbNqwmenUQDG_m51aeeCvguEKHvq2rv6kbWstiYbi83Zw0VTsm-xxJ8ROjTmDT-hKySyExhSrjQl6mc_HOll5d9g3NheMAiMBTMXwlOKTO-PQpsDtzHdj_pOXdKwXiwdl6dGzFAnqc3ZobTOXePAKzruOebvbY3izbxzMKqFO3_m0UECavH1VmwYlwUe8euyFOU4s1U-MdQvcGrAJm28haFPcgBmL1QZaOb_Z4JVZ1DiCFdkDQKjfxoyyUa0lEs661JcR7K8Bgpoi6jX0WIHEijM3GzVgyhZP3ELvQw5AnLjhXBlorEIOozNHL-9kooCnahl-WGWu3Z-Rf4MNl5VRvzxSJOJFyWBNApiQZJgJ-L_ZkElhQwnrAlUeOElcEQkbDweUXzSx3DhUD4fESeOFm4u9r8MYhOXZWbWwwcBMLDsgtcpmI88hX8xBOeO6C5F_rz-7o5U=w1684-h861-s-no?authuser=1" alt="tribute page for alexander fleming">
          <p class="project-title">
          <span class="code">"Tribute Page"</span>
          <span class="code"></span>```
````

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
 <main>  
    <div class="tribute">
      <h1>Alexander Fleming</h1>
      <p class="undertitle">Pioneering Penicillin Scientist</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgp">
    <img class="fleming"src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/183FB/production/_113832399_aleksandarflemingsasuprugom1954.jpg" alt="Alexander Fleming and his wife">
   <p class="pimg">The man who saved millions of people, Alexander Fleming</p>
</div>
</main>
<div class="title2">
    <h2 >
        Here's a time line of Alexander Fleming's life:    
    </h2> 
    <ul>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1881</strong>
            
         - Born in Lochfield, Scotland.
        </li>

         <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1901</strong>
            
            - Fleming joined St. Mary's Hospital Medical School after working hard to get qualified.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1904</strong>
            
            - Fleming passed his first medical exams and became a surgeon. As the search for the "Magic Bullet" continued, he looked for new ways to handle disease-causing microbes.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1909</strong>
            
            - Qualified to do surgical work, but he remained interested in the treatments of infections. He became an assistant bacteriologist to Sir Almroth Wright, who was a pioneer in vaccine therapy and immunology.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1915</strong>
            
            - Fleming married Sally (Sareen) McElroy in 1915. They had a son, Robert.


        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1921</strong>
            
            - Discovered the lysozyme, an enzyme occurring in many body fluids with a natural antibacterial effect.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1928</strong>
            
            - Discovered penicillium mold contaminating a dish with staphylococcus bacteria. Penicillin would eventually be considered by many to be “The Magic Bullet”, treating bacteria-caused diseases.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1929</strong>
            
            - Fleming used the name penicillin for the antibiotic.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1929</strong>
            
            -  Published a report on penicillin in the British Journal of Experimental Pathology. He tried to grow and purify the mold, but was relatively unsuccessful, and although he was involved in the development of penicillin afterward, Fleming let Howard Florey and his team at Oxford University do most of the work leading up to mass production.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1945            </strong>
            
            - Awarded the Nobel Prize in Medicine along with Florey and Ernst Chain.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1953</strong>
            
            - Married his second wife Dr. Amalia Koutsouri-Vourekas, a Greek colleague at St. Mary's Hospital where Fleming had been attached throughout his life after Sareen died in 1949.
        </li>
        <li class="timeLine">
            
            <strong>1955</strong>
            
           - March 11th, 1955: Alexander Fleming died of a heart attack, and to this date remains a revolution himself, with "a position of immortality," in Ernst Chain's words.
        </li>
    </ul> 
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.tribute{
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    
text-align: center;

transform: translate(0, 60%);
background-color: rgba(51,51,51,6%);
padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
padding-top: 1.7rem;
font-size: 1.3rem;
}

h1{
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.undertitle{
    color: orangered;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-style: italic;
}
.imgp{
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(0 ,20%);
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;  
 

}
.pimg{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-weight: 10;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-bottom: 14rem;
}
.title2{
    padding-top: 3rem;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(0%, 7%);
    padding-bottom: 40rem;
   background-color: rgba(51,51,51,6%);
}
h2{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-weight:  bolder;

}

.timeLine{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: left;
  padding-left:30rem ;
  font-family: Garamond;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-right: 20rem;

  
}
```

I tried padding to .timeline,.title2
for the text thats not  aligned right like the first line is good but the second is middle aligned.
and for the spacing i tried padding but it just moves the whole thing!

```
      HERE IS THE IMAGE THAT MIGHT HELP
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAlNg.png)